# Explorer now select files in empty space how to go back?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, selection

I am having problem with selecting files, before RS3 when I wanted to select files I just used mouse to select over file names they way it handled was like this:

Each file selection space was as much as it's name if I started my selection at the end of a filename , other files that didn't have that much space wouldn't be included.

- Aero Space.pdf
- mew~~.jpg
- jackie chan Movies List.xls
- some creepy thing_re.rar

So if I stared at **.rar** upwards first two files wouldn't have been included, but now they do, everything share the same selection space as the one having the most.

**It Was like this**

[image: Something like this]

**now its like this**

[image: New Update Files Selection]

I could have more space to work with copy, paste or use context menu on the folder not files, not it's too jammed up. how can I fix this?

Comment: 1709 has been out since Sept 2017.  Have you had this problem that long?

Comment: I have encountered this problem since 1703 , that's how long I remember